# Android Constraint Layout - Alignment of childrens

Tags: android, constraints

So I have a constraint layout with height `wrap_content` and width `match_parent`. I would like to know

1. How to align a `button` to the **centre** of a `recycler view` if they are rendered horizontally.
2. How to align a `button` to the **centre** of a `LinearLayout`(which will be populated later).. if they are rendered horizontally.

I tried `constraint.Guideline` but it seems not working because of constraint layout  `wrap_content` height. any suggestions?

Comment: got your result for first case but not in second (linearlayout)it has fixed height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe for other people this answer can be useful.

We can have an empty view below recycler view or linear layout.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerview"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />
```

now align button to the centre of parent top and this view.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_view"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="recyclerview"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

This should do the work :)

Answer (score 0):

To centre align, you need to set left and right align with respect to parent. e.g.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```