# Android: How to add space between added Buttons

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button

as the title states, i would like to add some space between added Buttons.

Code:

```
ConstraintLayout cst= (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.idButtonset);
cst.addView(this.addButton("Buttname0", R.id.svId));

Button fbutton= new Button(this);
fbutton.setText("Button 1");
Button sbutton = new Button(this);
sbutton.setText("Button 2");
cst.addView(fbutton);
cst.addView(sbutton);
```

**Issue**: It adds the buttons on top of each other.

**What i tried**:

```
fbutton.setPadding(30,30,30,30);
sbutton.setPadding(40,35,40,35);
```

**Issue**: margin isn't supported, padding - works but it isn't creating space between added Buttons.

**Question**: How to add Buttons i such a way in which they are added with space between ?

Comment: please check out this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728255/in-android-how-do-i-set-margins-in-dp-programmatically

Comment: what's the problem with margin?

Comment: Isn't supported/doesn't work

Comment: Try this for a ConstraintLayout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213359/android-constraint-layout-alignment-of-childrens